# Inserting into cassandra using hector on Glassfish 3.1

Tags: eclipse, jsp, glassfish, cassandra, hector

Im trying to insert a keyspace into cassandra using hector and the SchemaManipulation example given from the hector wiki.

```
package net.zanity.live;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.BasicColumnDefinition;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.BasicColumnFamilyDefinition;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.*;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorException;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;    

/**
 *
 * @author zznate
 *
 */
public class SchemaManipulation {

private static final String DYN_KEYSPACE = "YOUWantToSeeThis";
private static final String DYN_CF = "DynamicCf";
private static final String CF_SUPER = "SuperCf";

private static StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", "localhost:9160");

    try {
        if ( cluster.describeKeyspace(DYN_KEYSPACE) != null ) {
          cluster.dropKeyspace(DYN_KEYSPACE);
        }

        BasicColumnDefinition columnDefinition = new BasicColumnDefinition();
        columnDefinition.setName(stringSerializer.toByteBuffer("birthdate"));
        columnDefinition.setIndexName("birthdate_idx");
        columnDefinition.setIndexType(ColumnIndexType.KEYS);
        columnDefinition.setValidationClass(ComparatorType.LONGTYPE.getClassName());

        BasicColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDefinition = new BasicColumnFamilyDefinition();
        columnFamilyDefinition.setKeyspaceName(DYN_KEYSPACE);
        columnFamilyDefinition.setName(DYN_CF);
        columnFamilyDefinition.addColumnDefinition(columnDefinition);

        BasicColumnFamilyDefinition superCfDefinition = new BasicColumnFamilyDefinition();
        superCfDefinition.setKeyspaceName(DYN_KEYSPACE);
        superCfDefinition.setName(CF_SUPER);
        superCfDefinition.setColumnType(ColumnType.SUPER);



        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDefStandard = new ThriftCfDef(columnFamilyDefinition);
        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDefSuper = new ThriftCfDef(superCfDefinition);

        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition = 
            HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(DYN_KEYSPACE, "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy", 
                1, Arrays.asList(cfDefStandard, cfDefSuper));

        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDefinition);

        // insert some data

        List<KeyspaceDefinition> keyspaces = cluster.describeKeyspaces();
        for (KeyspaceDefinition kd : keyspaces) {
            if ( kd.getName().equals(DYN_KEYSPACE) ) {
                System.out.println("Name: " +kd.getName());
                System.out.println("RF: " +kd.getReplicationFactor());
                System.out.println("strategy class: " +kd.getStrategyClass());
                List<ColumnFamilyDefinition> cfDefs = kd.getCfDefs();
                for (ColumnFamilyDefinition def : cfDefs) {
                  System.out.println("  CF Type: " +def.getColumnType());
                  System.out.println("  CF Name: " +def.getName());
                  System.out.println("  CF Metadata: " +def.getColumnMetadata());  
                }


            } 
        }


    } catch (HectorException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
    cluster.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
  }

}
```

---

The jsp code:

```
<%@page language="java" import="net.zanity.live.*" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>GlassFish JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% out.println("CAKrE"); Test test = new Test(); out.println("sting displayed here: " + test.Testt()); %>
    After this text loads the cassandra schema test will run and prolly crash the webapp
    <% SchemaManipulation cI = new SchemaManipulation(); SchemaManipulation.main(new String [0]);  %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Im running this code in Eclipse 3.7.1 Indigo and the code when executed as a java application works and inserts into cassandra, but when i run it on the server it does not.

Cassandra is running on its default port as a local host and glasfish is also running on a local host on port 8080.

I think the issue is im not placing the hector jars in the correct place, the hector jars are already added to the buildpath but im not sure if that has added them to the server as well.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm failing to find useful documentation for cassandra.

EDIT: i have added the jar's to the server that was not the problem, issue is still unresolved.

Stack Trace of errors:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.<init>(AbstractCluster.java:44)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.<init>(ThriftCluster.java:21)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createCluster(HFactory.java:192)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:139)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:128)
    at net.zanity.live.SchemaManipulation.main(SchemaManipulation.java:36)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:61)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: You are saying it works when run locally, but not when cassandra is running on a remote server? Did you change the 'rpc_address' setting in the cassandra conf? It only listens on the local interface with the default settings.

Comment: both cassandra and glassfish are running locally.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with glassfish or jsp stuff so I'm not really sure how to debug. It might help if you add any stack traces or error output that is generated when things crash.

Comment: thank you for your help, i've added stack traces in an edin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add also the slf4j jar.

That should solve the problem.

In fact the stack trace says it cannot find the class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory which is included in the slf4j jar.

This jar is needed for hector, and indeed hector rises the exception.

Comment: I've added the jar files but I think i only added them to the eclipse project and not the actual server . 
BUILD PATHS: [link](http://prikachi.com/images/848/4399848B.jpg)
I though i added it but clearly i've not done it correctly. I did drop the cars in "C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib"
Any ideas on how to fix this, because when i try to add the jars to the build path of the webserver it adds them to the library folder anyway. (im really new to eclipse and this is where most of my issues are comming from =/ )